# How can I get Google Chrome to use the 64-bit Flash plugin?

Tags: linux, google-chrome, 64-bit, flash, plugins

```
[ me@fc14_x86_64 ~ ] google-chrome 
*** NSPlugin Viewer  *** ERROR: /usr/lib/mozilla/plugins/libflashplayer.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32

[ me@fc14_x86_64 ~ ] locate libflashplayer.so
/opt/google/chrome/plugins/nswrapper_32_64.libflashplayer.so # link to /usr/lib64/mozilla/plugins-wrapped/nswrapper_32_64.libflashplayer.so
/usr/lib/flash-plugin/libflashplayer.so # 32 bit
/usr/lib/mozilla/plugins/libflashplayer.so # link to /usr/lib/flash-plugin/libflashplayer.so
/usr/lib/mozilla/plugins-wrapped/nswrapper_32_32.libflashplayer.so
/usr/lib64/chromium-browser/plugins/libflashplayer.so # link to /usr/lib64/flash-plugin/libflashplayer.so
/usr/lib64/flash-plugin/libflashplayer.so # 64 bit plugin chrome should be using
```

Please tell me how I can get Google Chrome to use the 64-bit Flash plugin.

Comment: Is the chrome 64 bit ?

Comment: Yes. file /opt/google/chrome/chrome
/opt/google/chrome/chrome: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.8, stripped

Comment: Flash is included in Chrome. Something is wrong if it even tries to load external flash plugin.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Since when is Flash included with Google Chrome? I would even be more surprised if that was the case on Linux. In any case, he wouldn't have asked his question if it were automatically included; please use the comment feature instead if you meant to just make a remark instead of answering. This is a Q&A site, please don't use it like a forum... Thank you! :)

Comment: On Windows Chrome includes Flash.

Comment: @TomWijsman: Just in case ;) https://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=108086

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 separate problems.

First is the fact that the directory ~/.pki doesn't exist or is not writable. It is used normally for https.

The second problem of correctly installing the 64-bit flash plugin is maybe addressed here :
[Install native 64bit Flash Player 10 on Linux](http://www.myscienceisbetter.info/install-native-64bit-flash-player-10-on-linux.html).

Comment: Plz ignore the .pki line. The directory already exists. Regarding 64-bit flash plugin it is already installed but google-chrome fails to load it. `file /usr/lib64/flash-plugin/libflashplayer.so /usr/lib/flash-plugin/libflashplayer.so
/usr/lib64/flash-plugin/libflashplayer.so: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, stripped
/usr/lib/flash-plugin/libflashplayer.so:   ELF 32-bit LSB shared object, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, stripped`

Comment: Which is why I recommend reinstalling libflashplayer, but certainly only if your procedure was different from the above. Just to remark that some people had to recompile libflashplayer and Chrome on their computer before they really got it working.